# How to close an open file in java

Tags: java, excel, file, command

I am trying to write an excel file in java, and saving it in a shared folder. but if the file currently open at any system by anyone, it is throwing an error. So is there any way that we can close an excel file via a java command?

Comment: `outputStream.close();`, unless you want to close the file in another program.

Comment: I tried that but still it is throwing an error as this -->.

(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)

Comment: The first thing to establish is which process has the file open? Java, excel, something else? Do you know which process it is that has it open?

Comment: I also recommend you to check if the file is opened by another process, with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9341572/3779214

Comment: @tombrown52, just to check my application I am keeping it open in my system, just as normal excel file, at that time ti throwing that kind of an error.

Comment: I believe Excel opens files for exclusive write by default (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947172/write-to-file-that-is-open-in-excel)).  While you can configure an Excel workbook for multi-user share, I'm pretty sure this is a multi-reader, single-writer mode; I don't know how to have two concurrent writers.  Look at the previously cited link for a solution that waits for Excel to exit before writing your changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is actually open in someone's window (like you would open a ms word doc), then it's not going to be possible to close the file on their machine from a java program.  If you just need to one-time update that file, I'd recommend creating another file with a different name, and then manually replacing the contents of the desired destination with the contents of the file that you programatically create.

Comment: If you yourself have the file open, it is hard to force it closed. But if you are sharing the file and _someone else_ has it open, you can close it by using the `net files <id> /close` command (where `<id>` is the id of the specified file shown by running `net files` without any arguments)

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer in regards to that, but please let me know if it's insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

How to delete/close open excel file. so you have to auto close the file before delete...

```
    final File file=new File("E:\\book1.xlsx");
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "cmd /c taskkill /f /im excel.exe");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                   Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);// you need to wait 1-2 sec to close file before delete
                   file.delete();   

               } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Tried this approach and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the way the file is opened, you may be able to execute the command `net files <id> /close` via `Runtime.exec()`. You can also combine the `psexec` command to close files on remote computers.

This answer seems to describe a similar situation, you just need to make java run the commands:
https://superuser.com/questions/643916/remotely-close-open-shared-files